# Increase all elements in MutableList by 1 the Kotlin way

Tags: kotlin

I have a list

```
val result = MutableList(N) { 0 }
```

I want to increase 1 for elements in the list `result`

this works

```
for (item in result.withIndex()) {
                result[item.index] = result[item.index] + 1
}
```

but is there more kotlin way of doing it? like `it-> it+=1` ? I got val cannot be reassigned using this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Kotlin way" would be not to mutate lists at all, but to produce a new list instead using something like `.map{ it + 1 }`

But if you do want to use `mutableList` for some reason, `replaceAll` is a valid option:

```
result.replaceAll { it + 1 }
```